# AES in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption

Is there a *javascript* function, which inputs a string and a password and returns it in AES? I found the webpage http://aesencryption.net/ but it only shows PHP examples. I (*of course*) also need a function which inputs an encoded string and a password and returns the string. I could't find anything useful in the other stackoverflow pages about this. And I absolutely **must use** *javascript* (*I do have jQuery too*). The number of bits doesn't matter.

*Thank you in advance*

Comment: It would be foolish to use any encryption code in browser Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

AES in JavaScript is unsafe, since everybody can view the source / key used to encrypt/decrypt the data. [More info](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/).